# Keep shell focus when opening another program

Tags: powershell, batch-file, focus

I have a simple .bat file that I use to flush the contents of a file, open said file in notepad++ and then start mysql with logging to this file. My question is, is there a way to maintain focus on my shell when opening the file in notepad++? (I can totally translate this into a powershell file, I just haven't made one before and was more familiar with bat files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell:

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
$wshell.Run('notepad++',7)
```

For more info about what that number means and what your options are: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx